# Error creating DB in bicgcouch with database_dir moved

Tags: bigcouch

I have a cluster setup and I've moved the data dir from /opt/bigcouch/var/lib to /bigcouch

I changed the following lines in  /opt/bigcouch/etc/default.ini

```
database_dir = /bigcouch
view_index_dir = /bigcouch
```

I'm having a issue where if I try to create a new DB it returns JSON saying the DB was created but the actual DB is not created

I have the owner of the dir set to bigcouch

If I create the DB

```
curl -X PUT localhost:5984/testDB
```

and then

```
curl localhost:5986/dbs/_all_docs
```

I get zero records back

Comment: In your first `curl`, you create `testDB`, but then you request `_all_docs` from `dbs`. Is that a typo?

Your `PUT` request creates the database, but no documents therein. Shouldn't `_all_docs` then correctly return zero documents, as it does?

Answer (score 1):

If you edited the .ini file by hand you'll need to restart bigcouch. I suggest using _config instead in general.

Comment: and /bigcouch is owned by the user and group that bigcouch is running as?